# Using CheckStyle in NetBeans and configuring the CheckStyle rules

Tags: java, netbeans, checkstyle

I am using NetBeans 6.5. For CheckStyle, I have downloaded and installed the `nbcheckstyle.nbm` plugin. I am able to use CheckStyle with this plugin.

I want to configure the rules to be checked. I am not able to do it as it is an `.nbm` file. Any suggestion on how to configures the rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the "Config file" in the Options dialog.

This can be seen in the [screenshot](http://www.sickboy.cz/checkstyle/screenshots.html). (Set as netbeans_checks.xml).

Comment: I didn't know I downvoted it.  :/  I think maybe it was an inadvertent click, but I tried to change it and it wouldn't let me unless it was edited.

Comment: Over six years later this answer remains valid for NetBeans 8. The only point I'd add is that you need to restart NetBeans for your config file to become effective.